# Automate overwrite confirmations in PowerShell FTP Client Module

Tags: powershell, ftp, upload

I have a script that puts some files to FTP servers, so I have a list of servers IP ($FTPServer) and directory from files are uploaded (\Upload).

There is used PSFTP module https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb.

The problem is, the files that I upload already exist on servers and every time I'm asked about overwrite. I need to automate this thing.

> A File name: ... already exists in this location.
>   What do you want to do?

I was trying to put `-Confirm:$false`, but I must do something wrong.

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
{
    foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
    {
        Start-Transcript -Path $results
        Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line" 
        Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive 
        $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession 
        Write-Host -Object "Uploading $FILE..."
        Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Confirm:$false
        Stop-Transcript
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is PSFTP Modeule https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add-FTPItem` has `-Overwrite` switch, not `-Confirm`.

```
Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite
```

Comment: Ok, it works good. Thanks. Now I would like to have some file which contain information about success or failure uploading. How to extract info about success or failure from output?